# Docker - Composer Install - "requires ext-soap"

Tags: php, docker, soap, docker-compose

This morning I've to build a new docker and I'm getting the following issue, I've already tried installing soap through dockerfile and still no luck.

Is there something I'm missing?

> Problem 1
> - clearbooks/clearbooks-soap-php is locked to version 1.0.16 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - clearbooks/clearbooks-soap-php 1.0.16 requires ext-soap * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> -
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-exif.ini
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-gd.ini
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pcntl.ini
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini
> - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

I've noticed when running `php -m` - soap isn't actually there.

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:

  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: customphp/latest
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: localdb
      MYSQL_USER: localdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY  composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    bash \
    curl \
    nodejs \
    npm

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install xml mysqli pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl soap gd
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xml mysqli pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl soap gd

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN addgroup -g 1000 www && adduser -G www -g www -s /bin/sh -D www

RUN chown www:www /var/www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

RUN composer install

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm-alpine"]
```